# INSERT INTO problems

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I'm trying to do simple operation but i have 2 problems.
1. Script not working:
html file

```
<input type="text" name="traceability" id="traceability_1" maxlength="8" />
<input type="password" name="operator" id="operator"/>
$sql="INSERT INTO x_23_5_14 ( traceability, operator)VALUES
('$_POST[traceability]', '$_POST[operator]' )";
if (!sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql)){
print('Error');
 echo"   ".sqlsrv_errors() ."\n";
} else {
echo "1 record added";
}
```

1. Why ".sqlsrv_errors() always return array?

Comment: read the manual for `sqlsrv_errors()` Do you have sqlsrv installed on your server? What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And sqlsrv_errors() returns an array. you need to `var_dump(sqlsrv_errors())` instead.

Comment: So your PHP code isn't contained by delimiters? And 1. - because that is what sqlsrv_errors() is designed to do.

Comment: just array nothing else

Comment: I'm no PHP wizard, but first; You need to set a codeblock with the `<?php` and `?>` tags around your code. A hello world script would look like the following: `<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> `. Secondly, is this code block inside at .php file? To answer your 2. question, thats what the sqlsrc_erros() returns, an array. Loop through it if you want the errors.

Comment: Try `print_r(sqlsrv_errors());`

Comment: @Daniel i's just block inside php dont wory

Comment: Errors: ErrorArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S02 [SQLSTATE] => 42S02 [1] => 208 [code] => 208 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'x_23_5_14'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'x_23_5_14'. ) ) 1

Comment: How to check sqlsrv instaled or no?

Comment: @Daan how to check sqlswr instaled or no?

Comment: check your `phpinfo()`

Comment: @Daan PDO drivers  mysql, sqlite, sqlsrv    pdo_sqlsrv support enabled sqlsrv support enabled

Comment: @klapsius Ok thx thought you had to install it manually

Comment: @Daan could you explain how? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```